# How can I parse a Google sheet using getJSON (or other way)?

Tags: javascript

I’ve a stupid question. Here’re two links:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D1vL8EI0uRzeiGM-A8hZLgUCexXrocw5B_qTGnCekNE/pubhtml
```

And

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1D1vL8EI0uRzeiGM-A8hZLgUCexXrocw5B_qTGnCekNE/od6/public/basic?alt=json
```

When I open the first link in a browser, I can see a table itself, and when I open the second link, I can see some data in JSON.
What is the general rule of such a link conversion? Here are another link for example:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vS6D5wKWv4IfazLPFrphtG9lL4p4s4Zysmc40kGD22yqsaVhQXLef7M30DbwGT_MpNKHi5dplcQtB3d/pubhtml
```

How should I transform the link to get JSON? I’m going to use jQuery function `getJSON` to get the contents of a Google sheet. But what a URL should I give to the function?
And are there any other ways to access the contents of a table using JS?

Excuse me for my english!

Answer (score 1):

You should try google sheet api for working with  sheet

[Google sheet api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)

[Demo](https://gist.github.com/paulgambill/cacd19da95a1421d3164)

Comment: Thank you. Now I have a Client id and an API key. But what to do next? I tried to run the example code and got following error: `{
  "error": "idpiframe_initialization_failed",
  "details": "Not a valid origin for the client: http://[/*my domain name*/] has not been whitelisted for client ID [/*my client id*/]. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
} ` How can I whitelist it? I tried "domain verification", but this did not solve the problem

Comment: Please add your domain in google console white list